# Why the dereference operator preserves polymorphism (late binding) in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

It is well-known that "Virtuals are resolved at run time only if the call is made through a
**reference or pointer**.".  Thus, it is surprising to me when I find the **dereference operator** also keeps the dynamic binding feature.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct B {
  virtual void say() { cout << "Hello B" << endl; }
};

struct D : B {
  void say() override { cout << "Hello D" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    D *ptr = new D();
    B *p = ptr;
    (*p).say();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello D
```

**Question:** What the compiler dealt with the dereference operator *?

I thought it is done in the compile time. Thus when the compiler deference the pointer p, it should assumes that p points to a object of type B. For example, the following code

```
D temp = (*p);
```

complains

```
error: no viable conversion from 'B' to 'D'
```

Comment: This is exactly a call made through pointer. How would you make a call without dereferencing first?

Comment: pointers and references are types.  The dereference operator is a _function_ (ish).  So the real question is, "what is the return type of the dereference (pseudo)function?"

Comment: Do bear in mind that `(*foo).bar` is equivalent to `foo->bar`

Comment: Dereferencing does not create a new object. It means *use the object stored at that location* (or rather, in C++ speak, *use that object*, because an object *is* a memory region).

Comment: this question probably has more to do with vtables and dynamic dispatch than with "pointers" per se .

Comment: "Well-known" to whom? All the _wrong_ people?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well if you know the dynamic type at compile-time you don't need to use dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @dyp: Then you simply `static_cast`, but is that relevant here?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is an excerpt from the book "C++ Primer 5th edition".

Comment: @PengZhang: Then it's making some simplifications, because that is simply false, as explained below. From a basic standpoint it may _appear_ to be true due to conventional usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derefencing/indirection operator `*` doesn't itself actually do anything.
For example, when you write just `*p;` the compiler may ignore this line if `p` is just a pointer.

What the `*` does is change the semantics of read and write:

```
int  i = 42;
int* p = &i;

*p = 0;
 p = 0;
```

The `*p = 0` means *write to the object `p` points to*.
Note that in C++, an *object* **is** a region of storage.

Similarly,

```
auto x =  p; // copies the address
auto y = *p; // copies the value
```

Here, the read from `*p` means *read the value of the object `p` points to*.

The value category of `*p` only determines which operations the C++ language allows
on expressions of the form `*p`.

References are really just pointers with syntactic sugar.
So trying to explain what `*p` does by using references is circular reasoning.

---

Let's consider slightly changed classes:

```
class Base
{
private:
    int b = 21;
public:
    virtual void say() { std::cout << "Hello B(" <<b<< ")\n"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    int d = 1729;
public:
    virtual void say() { std::cout << "Hello D(" <<d<< ")\n"; }
};


Derived d;
Derived *pd = &d;
Base* pb = pd;
```

One weird, but I think allowed memory layout looks like this:

```
$$2d graphics mode$$

        +-Derived------------+
        |    +-Base---+----+ |
        | d  | vtable | b  | |
        |    +--------+----+ |
        +----^---------------+
        ^    | pb
        | pd


$$1d graphics mode$$

name    #    /../   |d       |vtable          |b       |
address #   /../    |0 1 2 3 |4 5 6 7 8 9 1011|12131415|16
                     ^        ^
                     | pd     | pb

pd == some address
pb == pd + 4 byte
```

When we convert from `Derived*` to `Base*`, the compiler knows the offset
of the `Base` subobject inside a `Derived` object,
and can compute the address value for this subobject.

The vtable pointer is stored, for single nonvirtual inheritance,
in the least derived type that has a virtual function.
It is changed by derived classes roughly as seen [in this implemenation/simulation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d13ae50553c6654).

When we now call

```
pb->say()
```

which is *defined in the C++ Standard as*

```
(*pb).say()
```

the compiler knows from the type of `pb` (which is `Base*`), that we call a virtual function.
Therefore, the `(*pb).say()` means *look up the entry for `say` in the vtable
**of the object `pb` points to**, and call it*.
The part *of the object `pb` points to* is what allows polymorphism.

On the other hand, when we copy

```
Base b = *pb;
```

What happens is that the vtable pointer is *not* copied.
This would be dangerous, because `Derived::say` might try to access `Derived::d`.
But this data member isn't available in an object of type `Base`,
which we're currently creating (in the copy ctor of `Base`).

Comment: "What happens is that the vtable pointer is not copied." This is the key! C++ primer says the synthesized copy/assignment constructor only does member-wise copy. Apparently, the vtable pointer is not a 'member'.

Comment: @PengZhang Exactly. I'd consider it an *implementation detail*, though that doesn't mean very much.

Answer (score 8):

On the surface of it, this is an interesting question, because absent an overload of unary `*`, dereferencing results in an *lvalue `B`*, not a reference type. However, even starting to go down this line of reasoning is a red herring: expressions *never* have reference types, as the reference is immediately dropped and determines the value category. In that sense, the unary `*` operator is very much like a function returning a reference

In fact, the answer is that your initial assertion is incorrect: **dynamic dispatch does not at all rely on references or pointers**. It is references and pointers that enable you to prevent *slicing*, but once you have some expression referring to your polymorphic object, any old function call will do.

Also consider:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base::foo()\n"; }
   void bar() { foo(); }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
   virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Derived::foo()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.bar();    // output: "Derived::foo()"
}
```

*([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d3b31109a9f3312))*

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure if I like the *dynamic dispatch does not at all rely on references or pointers*. The vtable uses function pointers (and it has to), and the object needs to have a pointer to the vtable or store the vtable itself. Slicing doesn't even have to prevent dynamic dispatch, it's just that the C++ constructors don't copy that pointer but set it up for each object individually if I'm not mistaken (which is a good thing because of *potentially* missing derived class data members).

Comment: @dyp: The fact that `(*p).foo()` performs dynamic dispatch while `(*p)` is of neither pointer or reference type is precisely the phenomenon that the OP is asking about, and it's plainly visible! (Whether pointer semantics are used in the _implementation_ of virtual dispatch is neither here nor there, I posit.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: leaving aside the allegation of "derogatory" and "add nothing", I think it's *possible* for you and your upvoters to make some constructive progress by considering `deref(p)` where `deref` is return `T&`. The type of the expression after adjustment is just `T` (§5/5), and it's an lvalue expression. So, it's effectively the same as `*`, an lvalue expression of type `T`. And it tells you what's going on here. More precisely, it *can* tell you what's going on.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Yes, and an lvalue expression of type `T` is not of a reference type. So what's the problem?

Comment: I think your example does not explain my question. The definition of d.bar() is "this->foo()". So the foo() is called through "pointer".

Comment: @PengZhang: It does not say `this->foo()`; it says `foo()`. However, I had a feeling that you were going to say this, and you're not entirely incorrect, in that it is not as good an example as your original `(*p).foo()`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: this answer is nonsense. it starts out by conflating lvalues with types, and goes downhill from there. consider the emphasized statement "dynamic dispatch does not at all rely on references or pointers". try to write code without pointers or references where dynamic dispatch plays any role (the closest you get is virtual calls from constructors): the conclusion is absurd. it can't be instructive. adding another a personal attack, as you attempt, doesn't help. flagging my comments and having them removed doesn't help either.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I found it instructive because it makes -- correctly, as I think -- the point that polymorphic behavior doesn't strictly depend on accessing the object through a pointer or reference. That's exactly what puzzled the OP. It's the _object itself_ which is polymorphic. Btw, I didn't attempt a personal attack but on the contrary tried to find a conciliatory way to express my bewilderment about the tone of the conversation. I also could not understand the point you tried to make and assume, perhaps  a little immodestly, that 9 out of 10 others couldn't either.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf As to your comment regarding the absurdity: Well, it's interesting to ask just _why_ we need pointers or references (although virtual function dispatch in an inherited function could count as a counterexample) if we are going to dereference them anyway. The reason is iiuc that we cannot have identifiers declared for a different type than the object they name. One of the reasons for that is the copy and assignment semantics of C++, unless perhaps one pulls stunts with some UB.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research, I think I have a reasonable (at least to me) answer for this question to share.

Assumptions (excerpted or paraphrased from the book "C++ Primer 5th"):

1. The dereference operator * on a pointer p, i.e. `(*p)` returns the object to which `p` points.
2. A object of a derived class `D: public B` *logically has* two parts, one is a sub-object of class B and the other part has members of class D. (This explains the "slicing

The `virtual mechanism of C++` I used to support this answer is from an article [12.5 The Virtual Table](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/). It convinces me **at least**. Below is a figure conceptually shows the `*__vptr` and the `VTable`s of the code in our question.
[image]

#### My explanation.

```
D obj_d;
D* ptr = &obj_d; // ptr is a pointer to type D,
                 // and points to obj_d, an object of type D

B* p = ptr;      // p is a pointer to type B and p points to the B subobject of obj_d.

(*p).say();
```

Since `p` is a pointer to type `B`, `(*p)` returns an object of type `B`, 
i.e., the sub-object of `(*ptr)`. Name this object of type `B` as `obj_b`.

However, the `*__vptr` of `obj_b` points to the VTable of `D`. Thus, when it calls 
`say()`, the function pointer of `say()` in the VTable of `D` points to the method that prints
`"Hello D"`

#### Experiment which supports my explanation.

```
 (&(*p))->say();  // outputs "Hello D"
```

#### Further Note

During calling a method of an object `x`, whether the polymorphism (dynamic binding of class members) happens depends on which VTable the `*__vptr` of that object it points to.

If we write `B obj_x(*p); (&obj_x)->say();` the output is "Hello B". This is because obj_x is a completely newly constructed object of type B using the synthesized copy constructor of struct B. Thus, the  `*__vptr` of obj_x points to the VTable of B.

Thanks to the help from [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp), we have a [**simulation of the virtual dispatch of this question**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d13ae50553c6654). In case of the webpage is removed by Coiliru, I stored the code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ckvhu39571dgehq/virtual_dispatch_simulation.cc).

Comment: @dyp Thank you for your comment. I add a figure and tried to make the comments more readable. Feel free to edit it. :-)

Comment: Btw. I prepared an implementation of the virtual dispatch, but discarded it because I thought that wouldn't answer your question. [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d13ae50553c6654) If you want, you can use it in your answer.

Comment: I pulled the last comment out of the codeblock. Hope that's OK.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how persistent coliru's archive is o.O

Comment: @dyp Thanks for helping write this answer up. Please feel free to edit it.

Comment: I've taken a different approach and tried to summarize operator `*`. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

Here you do not call (virtual) function with

```
p->say();
```

but with

```
(*p).say();
```

Same thing, just different notation. You call `virtual` function, and you resolve dynamicaly.

EDIT:

For `(*p).say()` compiler will do the following:

- from variable p load value (the address of something, in this case object of type B or subclass)
- get the address of a virtual table pointer (relatively to the obj address).
- go to table and call say() function (polymorphism in act).

Comment: I am more interested in the deeper reason. As the (*p) does return an object of type B.

Comment: @PengZhang it doesn't really *return* an object of type B. The result of dereferencing is "an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression [here: pointer] points" (from a C++ Standard draft, 5.3.1/1) Note that the result is *the* object the pointer points to, not a copy.

Comment: @dyp Thank you for pointing it out. So, what is the type of (*p)? a lvalue reference to type B or D?

Comment: @PengZhang See Lightness' answer. `(*p)` is an expression, and expressions don't have reference types. But it's *as if* `(*p)` had the type `B&`.

Comment: well you have a pointer (variable containing the address of something, in this case an object of type B probably). You load that address from memory location of p, go to that address (all in run time) you go to virtual table (compiler enters this code since it knows that the type was object of type B (or D)) and find function say() and call. Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score -2):

`*p` is a reference to a `B` object.

Comment: `*p` *is* a `B` object. And an lvalue. And an object that is not a complete object...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: it's an expression that refers to an object, so it's a reference to the object. that's what the words mean. the paragraph you cite does of course not support your contention. which is meaningless since it has no observable effect.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The word "reference" is well-defined in C++. This is not "a reference". It is however an expression that _refers_ to the object in question, which is not the same thing.

Comment: The assertions of LRIO above is contradicted by numerous uses of "reference to" in the C++11 standard, uses where it does *not* refer to reference type. These cases include §20.7.2.3/1, §20.8.3/1, §20.8.3.1/1, §20.8.3.1/2, §20.8.3.2/1, §30.4.2/1, §30.6.4/5 and possibly even §5.17/6 about the assignment operator (although that's less clear). It is so because the people writing the standard are ordinary intelligent folks, able to understand the concept of context. It's a shame that the mods have removed most of this commentary thread on the assumption that LRIO's nonsense and flagging was valid.